# Best CouchDB wrapper for C#?

Tags: nosql, couchdb

There are so many options for that. Which one do you guys prefer?

Thanks!

Comment: i know it's subjective, just asking opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested almost all C# clients for CouchDB and settled down with [LoveSeat](https://github.com/soitgoes/LoveSeat) which is probably most up to date client for this database.